# php 7.0 Strings can bigger than 2^31,How Big?

Tags: php, string, php-7

I really did some work on it to understand that

[Source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.0alpha2/UPGRADING)

the upgrading note says

> Support for strings with length >= 2^31 bytes in 64 bit builds.

but I read this [link](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/size_t_and_int64_next)

and the `types.h` source code that strings length defined using `size_t`

it seems should be `2^32` on 32bit builds and `2^64` on 64bit builds I guess?

Comment: What do you do with 2^31 chars? :o

Comment: yes ,2^31B=2GB,when i do some php console shell ,i used to handler with that big strings from text file format such as json

Comment: Bit of speculation, but 2^64 is 18.4 exabytes, so if that was the maximum supported, the amount you'd be able to use would be limited by the RAM in the system the application was running on.  Therefore there might not be a specific limit stated, as it would be subject to variance across systems, and change over time as the maximum amount of RAM an operating system could support would be.

Comment: Correct ... so, as @gabe3886 says, limited by the RAM, as of today.

Answer (score 0):

It's now 2<sup>64</sup>-1 in practice, since that's what `size_t`, the C type used for the length of a string, usually is on a 64-bit system.

However, in practice you can't actually make strings that big, since no computer has been created that can use anywhere near that amount of memory.

What this *will* mean is that if you have a computer with 16GB of RAM you could conceivably create an 15GB string if you wanted. You're unlikely to ever need to, though.